# Does C# have an equivalent to Scala's structural typing?

Tags: c#, scala, duck-typing, type-systems, structural-typing

In Scala, I can define [structural types](http://codemonkeyism.com/scala-goodness-structural-typing/) as follows:

`type Pressable = { def press(): Unit }`

This means that I can define a function or method which takes as an argument something that is Pressable, like this:

`def foo(i: Pressable) { // etc.`

The object which I pass to this function must have defined for it a method called press() that matches the type signature defined in the type - takes no arguments, returns Unit (Scala's version of void).

I can even use the structural type inline:

`def foo(i: { def press(): Unit }) { // etc.`

It basically allows the programmer to have all the benefits of duck typing while still having the benefit of compile-time type checking.

Does C# have something similar? I've Googled but can't find anything, but I'm not familiar with C# in any depth. If there aren't, are there any plans to add this?

Comment: Almost a decade later and I don't see any news of structural typing coming in C#... I wonder why. They have it in Gosu, and that's surely got less developers working on it: https://gosu-lang.github.io/2014/04/22/structural-types-in-gosu.html.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, and no plans that I know of.  Only named (rather than structural) subtyping (e.g. interfaces).

(Others may want to see also

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominative_type_system

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_type_system

)

(A few people may point out some exotic corner cases, like the `foreach` statement using structural typing for `GetEnumerator`, but this is the [exception](http://community.bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2009/08/17/linq-to-ducks-bringing-back-the-duck-typed-foreach-statement-to-linq.aspx) rather than the rule.)

Comment: Another case would be a generic type argument with a default constructor constraint.

Answer (score 7):

There isn't a way to define structural types that has a particular function. There is a library that adds duck typing support to C# that can be found [here](https://github.com/deftflux/DuckTyping).

This is the example from Duck Typing project. Please note the the **duck typing happens at runtime and can fail**. It is my understanding also that this library generates proxies for the types that are duck typed, which is far cry from the elegant compile-time support that is enjoyed in Scala. This is most likely as good as it gets with this generation of C#.

```
public interface ICanAdd
{
    int Add(int x, int y);
}

// Note that MyAdder does NOT implement ICanAdd, 
// but it does define an Add method like the one in ICanAdd:
public class MyAdder
{
    public int Add(int x, int y)
    {
        return x + y;
    }
}

public class Program
{
    void Main()
    {
        MyAdder myAdder = new MyAdder();

        // Even though ICanAdd is not implemented by MyAdder, 
        // we can duck cast it because it implements all the members:
        ICanAdd adder = DuckTyping.Cast<ICanAdd>(myAdder);

        // Now we can call adder as you would any ICanAdd object.
        // Transparently, this call is being forwarded to myAdder.
        int sum = adder.Add(2, 2);
    }
}
```

This is the C# way of achieving the same thing using the good ol boring interfaces.

```
interface IPressable {
  void Press();
}

class Foo {
 void Bar(IPressable pressable) {
    pressable.Press();
 }
}

class Thingy : IPressable, IPushable, etc {
 public void Press() {
 }
}

static class Program {
 public static void Main() {
  pressable = new Thingy();
  new Foo().Bar(pressable);
 }
}
```

Comment: Surely the duck-casting library can fail at runtime if the method is not there?  Just want to be clear that it's not compile-time checking.

Comment: Obviously. I ll add a comment in bold that it happens at runtime and can fail.

Answer (score 5):

As others noted, this is not *really* available in .NET (as this is more a matter of the runtime than a language). However, .NET 4.0 supports similar thing for imported COM interfaces and I believe this could be used for implementing structural typing for .NET. See this blog post:

- [Faking COM to fool the C# compiler](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2009/07/07/faking-com-to-fool-the-c-compiler.aspx)

I didn't try playing with this myself yet, but I think it might enable compiler authors to write languages with structural typing for .NET. (The idea is that you (or a compiler) would define an interface behind the scene, but it would work, because the interfaces would be treated as equivalent thanks to the COM equivalence feature).

Also, C# 4.0 supports the `dynamic` keyword which, I think, could be interpreted as a structural typing (with no static type checking). The keyword allows you to call methods on any object without knowning (at compile-time) whether the object will have the required methods. This is essentially the same thing as the "Duck typing" project mentioned by Igor (but that's, of course, not a proper structural typing).

Comment: that's a bad hack and should not be used!

Comment: No static type checking defeats the purpose of structural typing, IMO.

Comment: @Ion: definitely :-), but maybe it could be used by some compilers @musicfreak: Yes, I agree, but maybe it's better than nothing.

Comment: @Tomas: isn't this (http://tomasp.net/blog/cannot-return-anonymous-type-from-method.aspx ) also kind of a very limited, poor-man's structural typing? Without static type checking and also without methods, but still. It's not applicable to the OP's question of course.

Comment: @Marucio: Yeah, I think it is. Anonymous types use structural typing, but only locally. I guess that if it worked globally, then it would be proper structural typing, but that cannot work (because two equivalent anonymous types from different assemblies are treated as different types - though the trick with COM in .NET 4.0 may be a workaround for that :-)).

Comment: @musicfreak Static typing and structural typing checking are not orthogonal -- Scala supports *both* nominative and structural typing (and it is statically typed). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2831175/does-c-have-an-equivalent-to-scalas-structural-typing.

Comment: I believe this is now available in .NET if you are using F#

Answer (score 1):

The awaitable pattern in C# can perhaps be interpreted as a limited, ad hoc instance of structural subtyping / existential typing. The compiler will only `await` objects that have access to a `GetAwaiter()` method that returns any `INotifyCompletion` object with a specific set of methods and properties. Since neither the 'awaitable' object nor the 'awaiter' object needs to implement any interface (except `INotifyCompletion` in the case of the latter), `await` is similar to a method that accepts structurally typed awaitable objects.