# Constraints on Generic Types in Methods in C#

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I have a method that asks for a type `<T>`. It only requires that this type have a `Count` property defined. How can I specify that as a type constraint that allows all objects for which `Count` is defined?

This is what I have currently:

```
    private static void writeData<T>(String fileName, T rawData) where T : ICollection
```

However, this won't work if I try to use it with an `IDictionary`. What else can I try?

**Update**: I think the problem is that I'm constraining it to the non-generic `ICollection`, instead of the generic `ICollection<E>`.

Comment: Define `this won't work`. This should work as is.

Comment: Do you mean with IDictionary<TKey, TValue>? Since IDictionary impelements ICollection

Comment: You are looking for something called "structural typing". See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2831175/does-c-have-an-equivalent-to-scalas-structural-typing which asks about a C# equivalent to the Scala construct. The answer I have found on the webs is (in short) "NO" :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code should work with an `IDictionary`, since it implements `ICollection`.
Note that it will not work with an `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>`, since it doesn't implement (non-generic-) `ICollection`.
If you want to accept generic collections, you can change it to

```
static void WriteData<TElement>(String fileName, ICollection<TElement> rawData)
```

By the way, you don't actually need to use generics here; you can just take a parameter of type `ICollection`, and callers can pass any derived type.
To take generic collections, you'll need a type parameter for the *element*, but not for the collection type.

To answer your other question, you cannot constrain a parameter by the existence of a property, except by making an interface.
Since there is no `ICountedEnumerable` interface in the framework, you're out of luck there.  (Unless you make your own interface and only allow custom collections that implement it)

Comment: @Generic: He's not using generics.  Otherwise, he'd need two type parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this at compile time.

You can use reflection to check if T has a Count method and then invoke it.

Answer (score 0):

in response to update: Then don't pass the dictionary. Pass the `dictionaryVariable.Values` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for something called [structural typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_type_system). (The accepted solution, while perhaps valid/appropriate, does not utilize structural typing.)

See (the SO question) [Does C# have an equivalent to Scala's structural typing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2831175/does-c-have-an-equivalent-to-scalas-structural-typing).

The short answer appears to be "no" although some [duck-typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) approaches are possible.