# What is "Structural Typing for Interfaces" in TypeScript

Tags: c#, typescript, structural-typing

In his [blog post](http://blog.markrendle.net/2012/10/02/the-obligatory-typescript-reaction-post) about TypeScript, Mark Rendle is saying, that one of the things he likes about it is:

> "Structural typing for interfaces. I really wish C# could do that"

What did he mean by that?

Comment: I've briefly read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2831175/does-c-sharp-have-an-equivalent-to-scalas-structural-typing which clarifies it a little, but still would like to know how it's used in TypeScript

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Basically, it means that interfaces are compared on a "duck typing" basis rather than on a type identity basis.

Consider the following C# code:

```
interface X1 { string Name { get; } }
interface X2 { string Name { get; } }
// ... later
X1 a = null;
X2 b = a; // Compile error! X1 and X2 are not compatible
```

And the equivalent TypeScript code:

```
interface X1 { name: string; }
interface X2 { name: string; }
var a: X1 = null;
var b: X2 = a; // OK: X1 and X2 have the same members, so they are compatible
```

The spec doesn't cover this in much detail, but classes have "brands" which means the same code, written with classes instead of interfaces, *would* have an error. C# interfaces do have brands, and thus can't be implicitly converted.

The simplest way to think about it is that if you're attempting a conversion from interface X to interface Y, if X has all the members of Y, the conversion succeeds, even though X and Y might not have the same names.

Answer (score 2):

Think about.

```
class Employee { fire: = ..., otherMethod: = ...}
class Missile { fire: = ..., yetMoreMethod: = ...}
interface ICanFire { fire: = ...}
val e = new Employee
val m = new Missile
ICanFire bigGuy = if(util.Random.nextBoolean) e else m
bigGuy.fire
```

What if we said:

```
interface IButtonEvent { fire: = ...}
interface IMouseButtonEvent { fire: = ...}
...
```

TypeScript will allow this, C# will not.

As TypeScript aims to work well with the DOM that uses “loose” typing, it is the only sensible choose for typescript.

I leave it up to the reader to decide if they like “Structural typing”…..