# RuntimeBinderException when trying to instantiate an array of a dynamic type (late-binding)

Tags: c#, arrays, dynamic, late-binding, activator

I am trying to use `Activator.CreateInstance()` to instantiate an array that has fields of a dynamic type (I get the type that I must use for array fields during the runtime as `Type arrayType = arrayFieldType.MakeArrayType()`).

```
singleSet.ZaznamyObjektu = Activator.CreateInstance(arrayType, new object[] { rowCount });
```

(`rowCount` is an integer.) I have chosen this approach according to [How do I create a C# array using Reflection and only type info?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3419456/how-do-i-create-a-c-sharp-array-using-reflection-and-only-type-info) but it keeps giving me RuntimeBinderException:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'PodperneZarizeniTypeZaznamObjektu[]'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

But I do not know how to make cast or conversion when I cannot use the exact name of the type. I have also tried to use `Array.CreateInstance()` but it was giving me similar exception:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Array' to 'PodperneZarizeniTypeZaznamObjektu[]'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: What's the type of `singleSet.ZaznamyObjektu`?

Comment: PodperneZarizeniTypeZaznamObjektu[]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **but it keeps giving me RuntimeBinderException:**
>
> *Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'PodperneZarizeniTypeZaznamObjektu[]'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)*

That doesn't look like a runtime exception at all. That looks like a compile time error.

In comments you are saying that the type of `singleSet.ZaznamyObjektu` is 
`PodperneZarizeniTypeZaznamObjektu[]`. `Activator.CreateInstance` returns an `object`, bear in mind that `CreateInstance` is potentialy valid for *any* type. You can't assign an `object` to an array typed property.

Your problem seems to be that you are simply missing a cast:

```
singleSet.ZaznamyObjektu = (PodperneZarizeniTypeZaznamObjektu[])Activator.CreateInstance(arrayType, new object[] { rowCount });
```

Now, do note, that this will fail miserably in the following scenarios:

1. `arrayField` is a *reference type* and there is no valid identity preserving reference conversion between an `arrayField` and a `PodperneZarizeniTypeZaznamObjektu`.

   ```
   (Mammal[])tigers; //valid
   (Insect[])tigers; //evidently not.
   ```
2. `arrayField` is a *value type* and its type is not `PodperneZarizeniTypeZaznamObjektu`'s type. Even if there is an implicit / explicit cast operator, it will fail; array type variance is not permitted with value types.

   ```
   (long[])(ints); //not valid even though an implicit cast
                   //from int to long exists
   ```

Comment: Thanks a lot! The more I try to solve it the more I know this is really impossible (e.g. due to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21345821/cast-with-a-type-variable and what you've written here). My last chance is to write separate cast for each possible class being instantiated.